# API call with RestClient works only in Debug in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-debugging

I'm implementing an MVC project, which in Back End it calls different Boomi Atomsphere APIs.

One of them is composed in two asynchronous calls.
The first ask for a token
The second get the data using the token.
I'm using the RestClient to do that. The strange thing is that in Debug mode it works and get all the values.
When I run the project normally I get no value.

This is an example of code:

```
 private async Task<ListenerDetails> getListenersForEnv(string atomID) {

        var client = getClient();
        var token = await getTokenListeners(atomID);
        string resourceListenerRecord = "/async/ListenerStatus/response/"+ token;
        var listenerRequestRecord = getRequest(resourceListenerRecord);
        var responselistenerRecord = await client.ExecuteAsync(listenerRequestRecord);

        var jsonoObjListenerRecord = JObject.Parse(responselistenerRecord.Content);
        ListenerDetails model = new ListenerDetails();
        model.listenerModel = mapper.Map<ListenerDetails>(jsonoObjListenerRecord).listenerModel;
        model.numberOfResults = mapper.Map<ListenerDetails>(jsonoObjListenerRecord).numberOfResults;

        var apiListenerResponse = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responselistenerRecord.Content) ? model : null;
        var apiListenerResponseDocument = responselistenerRecord.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && apiListenerResponse != null ? apiListenerResponse : null;

        return apiListenerResponseDocument;
    }


    private async Task<string> getTokenListeners( string atomID) {
        var client = getClient();
        string resourceTokenListenerRecord = "/async/ListenerStatus/query";
        string requestTokenListenerRecord = "{\"QueryFilter\" : {\"expression\" :{\"argument\" : [\""+ atomID + "\"],\"operator\" : \"EQUALS\",\"property\":\"containerId\"}}}";
        var listenerrequestRecord = getRequest(resourceTokenListenerRecord, requestTokenListenerRecord);
        var responseexecutionRecord = client.ExecuteAsync(listenerrequestRecord).Result;
        var jsonoObjexecutionRecord = JObject.Parse(responseexecutionRecord.Content);
        var modelDetail = mapper.Map<ListenerAsyncOperationTokenResultModel>(jsonoObjexecutionRecord).asyncToken;

        var apiResponseDocuments = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseexecutionRecord.Content) ? modelDetail : null;
        var apiResponseDocument = responseexecutionRecord.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted && apiResponseDocuments != null ? apiResponseDocuments : null;

        return Task.FromResult(apiResponseDocument.token).Result;
    }


private RestRequest getRequest(string resource, string requestData) {

        var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddJsonBody(requestData);

        return request;
    }

    private RestRequest getRequest(string resource)
    {

        var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        return request;
    }
```

Could someone tell me why it works only in Debug mode?

Comment: Is it possible you're not using `await` somewhere? In debug, as you step through the code it could be completing some operation before returning a Task and instead returns a result?

Comment: Hi user3953989, thanks for coming back. In the example code I just used await on await getTokenListeners(atomID);
and await client.ExecuteAsync(listenerRequestRecord);
So just to wait the get Token operation and then to wait the response to get all the data.
Don't know where else I could put await in this example code.
The first call getTokenListeners works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: My doubt is:
because I am executing already an async API call 
"/async/ListenerStatus/response/"+ token;
Is it necessary call  'await client.ExecuteAsync(listenerRequestRecord);'?
Maybe should be client.ExecuteExecuteAsync(listenerRequestRecord); to run a sync call even if the API is async?

Probably the flow continues even if this async call does not terminate ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing await somewhere. After a quick look into your code there is a return vvariabe 'responseexecutionRecord ' which calls the method client.ExecuteAsync in the function getTokenListeners that could be awaited as it executes async method. You could remove the .result and just await it.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya,
thanks for your tips. I tried but the behavior still the same. It still work only if I set a breakpoint and going forward manually. Seems await doesn't handle the async method.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried:
[Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCNu1.png)

But retrieve still null
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiRXt.png)

Comment: You are getting 202 response means that the process is still processing. There should be changes to where Task is written and just await is enough for getting the data. Are you comfortable sharing  the code block which I could run locally?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I generate JWT, then send it signed with private key to API and should receive Bearer token for authorization to API. In my case, token JWT which I generated had bad time policy NotBefore. In debug mode, time passed and JWT had gaining authorization.

I figured out what caused the problem by using ExecutePost() instead of Post().